# How to split sentence into words, each in a new row after seeing a letter like "RN" in the sentence

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, that sometimes contains RN in the sentence.

I want to split the sentence into words and each in a new row whenever RN appears in any sentence.

For example:

**Before:**

[image]

**After :**

[image]

I only used:

```
df=df.assign(text=df['Default'].str.split('N')).explode('text')
```

Comment: Have you tried using `str.split('rn')`?

Comment: yes not working

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, the issue is that "RN" was not really recognized by python because it was bold with hidden signs and not really clear, so I replaced to ,R,N then I applied:

```
df=df.assign(text=df['Deafault'].str.split(',R,N')).explode('text')
```

and it works!

Comment: Fantastic! I think that you just needed to use the "Unicode" version because the character isn't in the table of ascii characters. You could also try convert it to ascii, that might actually help.